# How can I make the Program wait a Certain time?

Tags: c#

So what my exact problem is, is that I want the program to wait 3 seconds and if nothing happens id should execute whatever method I called. But if someone enteres something in these 3 seconds the timer should start again.

Threadsleep doesnt work because it blocks everything and you cant give any inputs.

For example, I have a Filter function and now I dont want to filter right after he entered a letter, I wait 3 seconds and if nothing happend I start filtering. I need this so my Program wont take to long for filtering every single letter.

[image: Here you can see how im Filtering by the Letter A but it instantly Filters it right after i typed A]

Here is my current code from the Filtermethod:

```
private void ContainsFilter(object sender, EventArgs e, TextBox textBox, DataGridView dataGridView, int columnIndex)
        {
            if (textBox.Text != "")
            {
                var value = "";
                var filterText = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Value);
                    value = value.ToLower();
                    filterText = textBox.Text;
                    filterText = filterText.ToLower();
                    if (value.Contains(filterText) == false)
                    {
                        dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
            {
                dataGridView.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Is this a console program or a GUI? If the latter, Winforms or something else? Also, can you show your current code?

Comment: Can you add some relevant code, like things you have tried

Comment: i think tasks are the best option. `await Task.Delay` for three seconds, then check if the task was _aborted_ - if not, continue. with each input, you abort the recent task and start a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy with [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0).
I try to give you a generic answer.

##### 1- Init the timer.

```cs
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Filter
};
timer.AutoReset = false; // To execute and filter once, not repeatedly every 3 seconds.
```

##### 2- Start the timer.

Basically when the text changed. Do this:

```cs
timer.Stop();  // Stop the previous timer (in case it is not elapsed yet.)
timer.Start(); // and start it again. To run after 3 seconds.
```

##### 3- Don't forget to dispose the timer.

When you fill you don't need it anymore. The program stopped, form closed, etc. Do this:

```cs
timer.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) class from C#.
With this class you can define an event that is generated after a certain time has passed. You can also stop the timer at any time. In your case, when the user starts giving inputs.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same request a while ago, the approach I used was to start searching when the user enters at least three letters